# How to use CreateView with crispy-forms in Django

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I want to use CreateView along with crispy-forms generated layout. However, it seems that everything I pass to *self.helper* in *forms.py* is ignored.
Form renders nicely, but only with fields generated by CreateView - all fields passed to *Layout* are missing.

My views.py

```
class MyView(CreateView):
    form_class = MyForm
    model = MyModel

    def form_valid(self, form):
        pass
```

My forms.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit, Layout
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import FormActions

from .models import MyModel

class MyForm(ModelForm): 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
        self.helper.layout = Layout( 
            FormActions(Submit('BlahBlah', 'BlahBlah', css_class='btn-primary')))

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['xxx', 'yyy']
```

My image_form.html:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
...
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
</form>
```

What else should I do to make it work?

Comment: I think the only thing wrong here is that instead of `form | crispy`, you should use `{% crispy %}`. See https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters.html#using-crispy-tag-because-it-rocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer at: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/Ovp_FgL3YwY

Had to change

```
{{ form|crispy }}
```

to

```
{% crispy form %}
```

Answer (score 18):

I have done it similar to @user3316785

My CreateView looks like:

```
class CreateDoktrinView(CreateView):
   model = Doktrin
   fields = ['name', 'description']

   def get_form(self, form_class=None):
       form = super().get_form(form_class)
       form.helper = FormHelper()
       form.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Create', css_class='btn-primary'))
       return form
```

and in the template I can simply use:

```
 {% crispy form %}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've solved this differently.

I've updated MyView in the following way:

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit

class MyView(CreateView):
    form_class = MyForm
    model = MyModel
    helper=None

    def form_valid(self, form):
        pass
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = 'id-exampleForm'
        self.helper.form_class = 'blueForms'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_action = 'url_action_call'
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Save', css_class='btn-primary'))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['helper'] = self.helper
        return context
```

This will give you the whole form with the crispy tag in your template by adding:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags  %}
{% crispy form helper %}
```

Answer (score 0):

here you have to use template tag
{% crispy form_name %}

NOTE: Crispy Filter Does not work here
so just replace {{ form|crispy }}  ->  {% crispy form %}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).