# AttributeError: type object 'Project' has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, attributeerror

I encountered the following in my Django files when I attempt to use the class based view `CreateView`.

```
AttributeError at /overview/new/
type object 'Project' has no attribute '_meta'
```

I have no idea why the `_meta` attribute is not there. I inherited my model from models.Model as usual, but I can't find any questions that have the same problem. I posted my files down below, can somebody help me fix this problem?

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import logout, authenticate, login
from django.contrib import messages
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView
from projects.models import Project, Task

class CreateProject(CreateView):
    model = Project
    fields = ['title', 'description']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .CustomIDConstructor import ID


class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='No title')
    description = models.TextField(default='No description')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customid = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=ID, editable=False, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from projects.views import ProjectsOverview, Project, CreateProject
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

urlpatterns = [
    path('', login_required(views.ProjectsOverview.as_view()), name='projects-projectsoverview'),
    path('project/<pk>/', login_required(views.Project.as_view()), name='projects-project'),
    path('new/', login_required(views.CreateProject.as_view()), name='projects-newproject')
]
```

Project_form.html:

```
{% extends "home/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container mt-4">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}

        <button style="background-color:rgb(130, 130, 130); color:white; border: none" class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Create new project</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Full traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /overview/new/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 168, in get
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 133, in get
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 66, in get_context_data
    kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 32, in get_form
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 101, in get_form_class
    return model_forms.modelform_factory(model, fields=self.fields)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 551, in modelform_factory
    return type(form)(class_name, (form,), form_class_attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 256, in __new__
    apply_limit_choices_to=False,
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 139, in fields_for_model
    opts = model._meta
AttributeError: type object 'Project' has no attribute '_meta'
[05/Mar/2019 14:00:15] "GET /overview/new/ HTTP/1.1" 500 115370
```

Comment: Add your `form.py` in question

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: @Akhilendra I didn't use a form.py, I tried the most basic use of createview that I found: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added the traceback into my post!

Comment: See this and modify as needed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885036/how-to-use-createview-with-crispy-forms-in-django

Comment: Can you add this : `print(Project, type(Project), Project.__module__, Project.__mro__)` in your view module (between the imports and the view class) and post the result here ?

Comment: @ChuckLaPress if you check the traceback, the exception happens way before we hit the template rendering part and we've not run any crispy code at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your URLs, it looks like you have a view `Project` which is clashing with the model `Project`.

```
path('project/<pk>/', login_required(views.Project.as_view()), name='projects-project'),
```

The simplest fix would be to rename that view, for example to `ProjectDetail`, and update the URL pattern.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem! Can't believe that my error was caused by such a small detail. Lesson learned!